# Writing a Custom Broker using JMS on WSO2 CEP

Tags: jms, wso2, broker

I want to create custom broker using JMS on WSO2 CEP. I created two classes, NewJMSBrokerType and NewJMSBrokerTypeFactory.

I extends JMSBrokerType for NewJMSBrokerType and implements JMSBrokerTypeFactory for NewJMSBrokerTypeFactor.

And I put `broker.xml` in `CEP_HOME/repository/conf`.
Following contents of `broker.xml`:

```
<brokerTypes xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/broker">
   <brokerType class="org.wso2.broker.new_jms.NewJMSBrokerTypeFactor"/>
</brokerTypes>
```

Finally, I restart CEP server, following error messages got dumped on console.

```
[2013-09-05 22:07:44,681] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.BrokerService} -  org/wso2/carbon/broker/core/internal/brokers/jms/JMSBrokerTypeFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/broker/core/internal/brokers/jms/JMSBrokerTypeFactory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.builder.BrokerServiceBuilder.registerBrokerType(BrokerServiceBuilder.java:122)
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.builder.BrokerServiceBuilder.createBrokerService(BrokerServiceBuilder.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.ds.BrokerServiceDS.activate(BrokerServiceDS.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerHandler.startEventBroker(EventBrokerHandler.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerBuilderDS.activate(EventBrokerBuilderDS.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:513)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.brokers.jms.JMSBrokerTypeFactory
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 71 more
[2013-09-05 22:07:44,687] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.ds.BrokerServiceDS} -  Can not create the broker service
org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.exception.BrokerConfigException: Can not process class org.wso2.broker.sol_jms.SolJMSBrokerTypeFactory
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.builder.BrokerServiceBuilder.registerBrokerType(BrokerServiceBuilder.java:137)
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.builder.BrokerServiceBuilder.createBrokerService(BrokerServiceBuilder.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.ds.BrokerServiceDS.activate(BrokerServiceDS.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerHandler.startEventBroker(EventBrokerHandler.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerBuilderDS.activate(EventBrokerBuilderDS.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:513)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/broker/core/internal/brokers/jms/JMSBrokerTypeFactory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.builder.BrokerServiceBuilder.registerBrokerType(BrokerServiceBuilder.java:122)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.brokers.jms.JMSBrokerTypeFactory
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 71 more
```

I entreat you to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the JMSBrokerType and JMSBrokerTypeFactory because they are internal java classes which are not allowed to exposed through OSGI service... You can only extend the BrokerType and BrokerTypeFactory to create your custom classes..

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: Thank you very mush for your speedy and proper reply.